# Multiple DataProviders Yii

Tags: php, yii

Hi I am new to Yii and what i am trying to do is i have hotels and its items and i want to display top rated. so in `siteController` I get the data very well. but I tried to get multiple dataproviders and render `index` page but it does not recognises the changed dataprovider name.

for ex

```
public function actionIndex()
    {
        // renders the view file 'protected/views/site/index.php'
        // using the default layout 'protected/views/layouts/main.php'

            $dataProviderHotel=new CActiveDataProvider('Hotel',array(
                'criteria'=>array(
                    'condition'=>'hotel_rating > 8',
                    ),
                    'pagination'=>array(
                        'pageSize'=>20,
                    ),
                ));

            $dataProviderItems = new CActiveDataProvider('Item',array(
                'criteria'=>array(
                    'condition'=>'hotel_rating > 8',
                    ),
                    'pagination'=>array(
                        'pageSize'=>20,
                    ),
                ));



            $this->render('index',array(
            'dataProvider'=>array($dataProviderHotel,$dataProviderItem),
        ));            
    }
```

and in view exception is thrown that dataProviderHotel undefined
view code is

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
        'dataProvider'=>$dataProviderHotel,
        'summaryText'=>'',
        'itemView'=>'_topHotels',
)); ?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be the following :

```
$this->render('index',array(
        'dataProvider1'=>$dataProviderHotel,
        'dataProvider2'=>$dataProviderItem
    ));
```

Then in your view :

```
 <?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider1,
    'summaryText'=>'',
    'itemView'=>'_topHotels',
 )); 
 ?>
```